# Counter - Examples

Tags: sectioning, environments, counters

People. Sorry about the English language.

I created an environment with some help here, and now I need help with the counter.

```
\newcounter{examplecounter}
\newenvironment{exemplo}{\begin{framed}\noindent \refstepcounter{examplecounter} {\textbf{Exemplo \arabic{examplecounter}.}} }{\end{framed}}
```

I'm using this environment on a large book, so i need to reset the counter by part, by section, or (if possible) even make it just like the part numbering, like example **part.chapter.#**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply load the `ntheorem` and `framed` packages and use this declaration in the preamble:

```
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremseparator\newline}
\newframedtheorem{example}{Exemplo}[\part]
```

Comment: I got an error with that code... 

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.sty:524:
Package nthe
orem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.

See the ntheorem package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.524 ...rfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}

Comment: Maybe you're loading `amstheorem`?

Comment: Yeah ;-;  now i'm trying again, with "\theoremseparator{\newline}"

Comment: `ntheorem` conflicts with `amsthm` since they touch upon the same environments. However, ntheorem has a `amsthm` compatibility mode (and it should be loaded with the `amsmath` option; the`thmmarks` option activates the end-of-proof symbol automatic placement).